# Image fitting in css grid

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid

I am not really familiar with HTML and CSS and I am having some problems with fixing my problem.

I am trying to fit the picture excatly on the grid and the grid to be visible in the center of the page which actually it is.

I saw that there are a lot of questions about this and I tried to look at the answers the questions got and try to fix my problem but it was actually not working. So I hope anyone can help me with this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="6.png" class="img"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="3.png" class="img"> </div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>  
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="3.png" class="img"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="7.png" class="img"></div>  
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>  
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>  
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="2.png" class="img"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div> 
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="2.png" class="img"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>  
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="3.png" class="img"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="4.png" class="img"></div>  
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>  
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div> 
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="2.png" class="img"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div> 
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="5.png" class="img"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>  
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="4.png" class="img"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="4.png" class="img"></div>  
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>  
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="8.png" class="img"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div> 
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="5.png" class="img"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>  
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="5.png" class="img"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="9.png" class="img"></div>  
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  background-color: #8B38BE;
  padding: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 700px;

}
.grid-item {
  background-color: #E0E7FF;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.grid-item > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your img has quite a lot of padding - is that what you are wanting or do you want the img to fill the grid square?

Comment: @AHaworth yes I want the img to fill the grid square and look good

Comment: If you want each img to fill its grid square you can do that using object-fit cover but if you give it all that padding it will just look very small within its square. Do you want padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay you can do it like this:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  background-color: #8B38BE;
  padding: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 700px;

}
.grid-item {
  background-color: #E0E7FF;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
.grid-item > img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

So in this case, you are placing img to be absolute and to have height and width same as grid-item. But then you will add `object-fit` which will make image fit nicely inside grid-item.

Comment: brate, it works for me for some images but for some of them they are being excatly as the height of the grid but it's not filling the grid excatly (width). Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean that images are bigger than grid-item and they are getting cropped?

Comment: Try removing `max-width` and changing it with `width`?

Comment: No images are not getting bigger then the grid-item it's just some of them fit perfectly and some of them are being like "cropped" the image is shown full how it is but its not filling the width of the gird the height its okay. I hope I am explaning it right.

Comment: perfect okay it works now, hvala.

Comment: Out of the countless stackoverflow questions and articles I scoured for "make image fit in css grid", this is the only one that worked. Thank you so much I will use this always

Comment: After searching everywhere, position absolute did the trick

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you are trying to center the grid, there are multiple ways you can do this though, im not sure what your looks like. Im not sure if its loading any CSS or not at all doing anything. If you wanted to you could make a div with everything in it and do something like:

```css
.grid {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used aspect ratio. Please update below css in your code.

```
.grid-item {
  background-color: #E0E7FF;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
 .grid-item > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.grid-item > img {}` I would just define it as a class (since you're telling it, it has a .img class. Further, remove padding and use height:100%

```
.img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}
```